# Install dwb browser

Tags: software-installation, make, debian

I try to install dwb on debian wheezy. There is a package but the version is old and I would like a newer version. The version in wheezy does not provide dwbem, suddenly I can not install flaskblock and therefore I can not run grooveshark. I tried to install via backport:

```
sudo apt-get install -t wheezy-backports dwb
```

But the version is the same as wheezy. Finally I tried to compile the source but it does not work, dependency problem:

```
git clone https://portix@bitbucket.org/portix/dwb.git
cd dwb
sudo make install
config.mk:106: *** Cannot find gtk2-libs or gtk3-libs. Arrêt.
```

Yet I have installed the header like libgtk2.0-dev. I also tried to install the meta package:

```
sudo apt-get install gtk+2.0
```

If someone has an idea for me to install a newer version of dwb on wheezy I'm interested.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, it was a dependency problem, lacked other packages, libwebkitgtk-dev, libjson0-dev, and libgnutls-dev.